# Should I use "would be" or "would've been" in this conditional?

Tags: conditionals, modal-verbs

Consider the following text:

"There are many beautiful hills and country parks in Hong Kong that I want to hike, but it's too hot right now. I would rather wait until the fall. What a pity! Hong Kong ___ a hiking paradise if not for the weather."

Should I use "would be" or "would've been" in the blank? Why?

Comment: Hong Kong will still be a hiking paradise in fall, so why not stick with "would be"?

Comment: [a] << Hong Kong **would be** a hiking paradise if not for the weather >> states (subjectively) an enduring fact. _The weather regularly mars things._ // [b] << Hong Kong **would have been** a hiking paradise if not for the weather >> refers (here) to the present season's weather being the spoiler, essentially preventing the desired (now; this summer) hiking from being a reality; this might or might not be a recurring problem. // You must choose which applies; neither is ungrammatical.

Comment: Ashworth's comment is the best answer here, it should be promoted to an actual answer.

Answer (score 2):

As commented, both versions are perfectly grammatical.

> 1: *Hong Kong **would be** a hiking paradise if not for the weather.*

Implies either 1a *...would be **right now*** OR 1b *...would be **all the time*** That's to say, only context determines whether it's the *current* weather that prevents it being a hiking paradise, or that it's *never* a hiking paradise because of the weather all year round.

> 2: *Hong Kong **would have been** a hiking paradise if not for the weather.*

Implies either 2a *...would have been **in the speaker's recent past*** (i.e. - during his currently ending holiday in HK) OR 2b ***...in some hypothetical alternate reality** [where HK has different weather]*.

---

If speaker is specifically expressing *current* regret that he couldn't go hiking very recently, option #2 is probably best (because Present Perfect implies strong connection to time of speaking). In all other contexts, I'd suggest sticking with option #1.

Answer (score 1):

Although both tenses are grammatical here, the present seems to fit better, and it would be difficult to pin down the meaning of the perfect version.

**would be** implies "would now be".

**would have been** could imply that it would now be, and would long have enjoyed a reputation for being, a hiking paradise.  Its status as hiking paradise would be well-established.